# ionic2 how to get checkbox status

Tags: angular, checkbox, ionic2

here is the context:

I have a list of users.

I also have a list of items and each item holds an Array of users.

The items list is displayed like that:

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ion-checkbox item-left [checked]="isChecked(item)" *ngIf="selected_user;"></ion-checkbox>
      <ion-label>
        {{ item.name }}
        <br>
        <ion-badge *ngFor="let user of item.users">{{ user.name }}</ion-badge>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Basically the checkboxes are revealed when a user is selected somewhere else.

What I am trying to do is to modify for each item its users array according to the status of the checkbox.

For instance, if `item_a.users` contain `user1` and `selected_user` is `user1` its checkbox revealed as `checked` (I have that already) but now if `item_b` and `item_c` will be checked I want to add `user1` to their users array and if `item_a` is unchecked I want to remove `user1` from its users array.

Is there any event to catch here? 
Is there a way to get all the status together in some data structure or I have to handle it individually for each item?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused by your question; if you have the isChecked function then you know if they're checked, can't you map some kind of function against this data to get what you're after?

Comment: `isChecked` is used to determine the initiate status of the checkbox. I will use the `ionChange` event for adding or remove items from the list as shown in the accepted answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the API docs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/checkbox/Checkbox/#output-events)
 You can use `ionChange` event.

In your html,

```
 <ion-checkbox item-left [checked]="isChecked(item)" (ionChange)="insertUserToArray($event)" *ngIf="selected_user;"></ion-checkbox>
```

In component add function:

```
insertUserToArray(item){
//check item.user and do stuff
}
```

Comment: After all this is most likely the easiest way to achieve that behaviour. Thanks.